# how to convert ejs template code to jade template code?

Tags: javascript, pug, ejs

convert ejs template code to jade template code:

```
<% if (theme.leancloud_visitors.enable) { %>
    <span id="<%- url_for(item.path) %>" class="leancloud_visitors" data-title="<%= item.title %>"></span>
<% } %>
```

I don't know when id is a varibale, how to get it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer.

Comment: Specifically, what have you tried so far in jade/pug?